# Unexpected namespace import import/no-namespace

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to import D3v4 in React to produce a Dash component. This is my code so far:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

function createBox(divId) {
    var svgContainer = d3.select(divId).append('svg')
                                     .attr('width', 200)
                                     .attr('height', 200);

 //Draw the Circle
   svgContainer.append('circle')
                        .attr('cx', 30)
                        .attr('cy', 30)
                        .attr('r', 20);
}

/**
 * ExampleComponent is an example component.
 * It takes a property, `label`, and
 * displays it.
 * It renders an input with the property `value`
 * which is editable by the user.
 */
export default class ExampleComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.plot = this.plot.bind(this);
    }
    plot(props) {
       createBox(props.id);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.plot(this.props);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        this.plot(newProps);
    }

    render() {
        const {id} = this.props;
        return (
            <div id={id}/>
        );
    }
}

ExampleComponent.propTypes = {
    /**
     * The ID used to identify this compnent in Dash callbacks
     */
    id: PropTypes.string

};
```

But when I try to prepublish Dash using `$ npm run prepublish` it throws the error:

```
error Unexpected namespace import  import/no-namespace
```

And it points back to `import * as d3 from 'd3';`

I am building off of the example provided by [Plotly](https://plot.ly/dash/plugins) on writing your own components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the [esling Docs](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/no-namespace.md):

> Reports if namespace import is used.

So you should change it to this:

```
import d3 from 'd3';
```

Or disable the rule if you must use the namespace (like mentioned in the eslint docs)

**Update**
After reading the [docs of d3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3) they use the same pattern so i assume there is no `default` export for `d3` hence this:

```
import d3 from 'd3';
```

might not work.
then either use a named import for individuals parts like this:

```
import {scaleLinear} from "d3-scale";
```

Or disable the rule like i mentioned above.

Comment: I tried this solution and it worked! I just had to also add `d3-selection` (the library I was using) to my dependencies. Thanks!

Comment: Just to add to this a bit, a very simple solution that disables the rule is just to use `// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-namespace` and then on the next line put `import * as d3 from 'd3';`